# How to automate mouse and keyboard?

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

Can i write a java program to automate mouse movements and clicks ??

Like, then i will be able to run the program and it will work like some human being is controlling the machine..

I know about the Robot class. Will that be a solution. Any thought is welcome...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the Robot class is for. Did you try it?

Comment: I didn't know much bout it before. Thanx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it's you again.
java.awt.Robot is the solution. try it yourself. Its easy to use. You can automate mouse and keyboard.

This is one such class which demonstrate the use of Robot class. I've written it a long time ago. I'm posting the full code. try it yourself..

```
package MyRobot;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyRobot {

Robot MYROBOT;
Color SCREEN[][];
int SCREEN_X;
int SCREEN_Y;
int WINDOW_X;
int WINDOW_Y;
int TYPE_DELAY = 0;
int MOUSE_DELAY = 0;
int SKILL = 0;
int X, Y;
int lastX, lastY;
int savedX, savedY;
int RED, GREEN, BLUE;
Color PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE;
Color PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_ON_MOUSE;
HashMap<Character, Integer> KEYMAP;
ArrayList<Integer> randKeys;
GraphicsEnvironment grEnv;
GraphicsDevice grDevice;
JPanel drawPanel;
BufferedImage bufImg;
Rectangle rect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyRobot().go();
}

void go() {
    initialize();        
    gotoxy(100, 100);
}

void initialize() {
    grEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    grDevice = grEnv.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    updateScreenInfo();
    setKeyMap();
    try {
        MYROBOT = new Robot();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Can't build the robot!", "Error", -1, 1, null, null, this);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    X = SCREEN_X / 2;
    Y = SCREEN_Y / 2;
    //MYROBOT.mouseMove(X, Y);
    PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE = new Color(184, 67, 44);
    PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_ON_MOUSE = new Color(210, 35, 2);
}

void updateScreenInfo() {
    SCREEN_X = grDevice.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    SCREEN_Y = grDevice.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    WINDOW_X = grEnv.getMaximumWindowBounds().width;
    WINDOW_Y = grEnv.getMaximumWindowBounds().height;
}

void setKeyMap() {
    KEYMAP = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    KEYMAP.put('q', 81);
    KEYMAP.put('w', 87);
    KEYMAP.put('e', 69);
    KEYMAP.put('r', 82);
    KEYMAP.put('t', 84);
    KEYMAP.put('y', 89);
    KEYMAP.put('u', 85);
    KEYMAP.put('i', 73);
    KEYMAP.put('o', 79);
    KEYMAP.put('p', 80);
    KEYMAP.put('a', 65);
    KEYMAP.put('s', 83);
    KEYMAP.put('d', 68);
    KEYMAP.put('f', 70);
    KEYMAP.put('g', 71);
    KEYMAP.put('h', 72);
    KEYMAP.put('j', 74);
    KEYMAP.put('k', 75);
    KEYMAP.put('l', 76);
    KEYMAP.put('z', 90);
    KEYMAP.put('x', 88);
    KEYMAP.put('c', 67);
    KEYMAP.put('v', 86);
    KEYMAP.put('b', 66);
    KEYMAP.put('n', 78);
    KEYMAP.put('m', 77);
    KEYMAP.put('1', 49);
    KEYMAP.put('2', 50);
    KEYMAP.put('3', 51);
    KEYMAP.put('4', 52);
    KEYMAP.put('5', 53);
    KEYMAP.put('6', 54);
    KEYMAP.put('7', 55);
    KEYMAP.put('8', 56);
    KEYMAP.put('9', 57);
    KEYMAP.put('0', 48);
    KEYMAP.put(' ', 32);

    randKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 44; j < 94; j++) {
        randKeys.add(j);
    }
    randKeys.remove(randKeys.indexOf(58));
    randKeys.remove(randKeys.indexOf(60));
    randKeys.remove(randKeys.indexOf(62));
    randKeys.remove(randKeys.indexOf(63));
    randKeys.remove(randKeys.indexOf(64));
}

void typeHuman(String letters) {
    MYROBOT.setAutoDelay(TYPE_DELAY);
    char[] letter = letters.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(letter[i]);
        try {
            if ((int) (Math.random() * SKILL) == (int) (Math.random() * SKILL) / 2) {
                int limit = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
                    int k = (int) (Math.random() * (randKeys.size() - 1));
                    manuPress(randKeys.get(k));
                }
                sleep(200);
                for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
                    backspace();
                }
            }
            if ((Character.isLowerCase(letter[i])) || (Character.isDigit(letter[i]))) {
                MYROBOT.keyPress(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
                MYROBOT.keyRelease(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
            } else {
                letter[i] = Character.toLowerCase(letter[i]);
                MYROBOT.keyPress(16);
                MYROBOT.keyPress(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
                MYROBOT.keyRelease(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
                MYROBOT.keyRelease(16);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            switch (letter[i]) {
                case '!': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(49);
                    break;
                }
                case '@': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(50);
                    break;
                }
                case '#': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(51);
                    break;
                }
                case '$': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(52);
                    break;
                }
                case '%': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(53);
                    break;
                }
                case '^': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(54);
                    break;
                }
                case '&': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(55);
                    break;
                }
                case '*': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(56);
                    break;
                }
                case '(': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(57);
                    break;
                }
                case ')': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(48);
                    break;
                }
                case '?': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(47);
                    break;
                }
                case '/': {
                    manuPress(47);
                    break;
                }
                case ':': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(59);
                    break;
                }
                case ';': {
                    manuPress(59);
                    break;
                }
                case '.': {
                    manuPress(46);
                    break;
                }
                case ',': {
                    manuPress(44);
                    break;
                }
                case '"': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(222);
                    break;
                }
                case '\'': {
                    manuPress(222);
                    break;
                }
                case '[': {
                    manuPress(91);
                    break;
                }
                case ']': {
                    manuPress(93);
                    break;
                }
                case '{': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(91);
                    break;
                }
                case '}': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(93);
                    break;
                }
                case '\\': {
                    manuPress(92);
                    break;
                }
                case '|': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(92);
                    break;
                }
                case '=': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(61);
                    break;
                }
                case '+': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(61);
                    break;
                }
                case '-': {
                    manuPress(45);
                    break;
                }
                case '_': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(45);
                    break;
                }
                case '`': {
                    manuPress(192);
                    break;
                }
                case '~': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(192);
                    break;
                }
                case '<': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(44);
                    break;
                }
                case '>': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(46);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("");
}

void type(String letters) {
    MYROBOT.setAutoDelay(TYPE_DELAY);
    char[] letter = letters.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(letter[i]);
        try {
            if ((Character.isLowerCase(letter[i])) || (Character.isDigit(letter[i]))) {
                MYROBOT.keyPress(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
                MYROBOT.keyRelease(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
            } else {
                letter[i] = Character.toLowerCase(letter[i]);
                MYROBOT.keyPress(16);
                MYROBOT.keyPress(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
                MYROBOT.keyRelease(KEYMAP.get(letter[i]));
                MYROBOT.keyRelease(16);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            switch (letter[i]) {
                case '!': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(49);
                    break;
                }
                case '@': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(50);
                    break;
                }
                case '#': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(51);
                    break;
                }
                case '$': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(52);
                    break;
                }
                case '%': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(53);
                    break;
                }
                case '^': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(54);
                    break;
                }
                case '&': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(55);
                    break;
                }
                case '*': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(56);
                    break;
                }
                case '(': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(57);
                    break;
                }
                case ')': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(48);
                    break;
                }
                case '?': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(47);
                    break;
                }
                case '/': {
                    manuPress(47);
                    break;
                }
                case ':': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(59);
                    break;
                }
                case ';': {
                    manuPress(59);
                    break;
                }
                case '.': {
                    manuPress(46);
                    break;
                }
                case ',': {
                    manuPress(44);
                    break;
                }
                case '"': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(222);
                    break;
                }
                case '\'': {
                    manuPress(222);
                    break;
                }
                case '[': {
                    manuPress(91);
                    break;
                }
                case ']': {
                    manuPress(93);
                    break;
                }
                case '{': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(91);
                    break;
                }
                case '}': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(93);
                    break;
                }
                case '\\': {
                    manuPress(92);
                    break;
                }
                case '|': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(92);
                    break;
                }
                case '=': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(61);
                    break;
                }
                case '+': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(61);
                    break;
                }
                case '-': {
                    manuPress(45);
                    break;
                }
                case '_': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(45);
                    break;
                }
                case '`': {
                    manuPress(192);
                    break;
                }
                case '~': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(192);
                    break;
                }
                case '<': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(44);
                    break;
                }
                case '>': {
                    manuPressSHIFTED(46);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("");
}

void typeln(String letters) {
    type(letters);
    enter();
}

void typelnHuman(String letters) {
    typeHuman(letters);
    enter();
}

void getRun() {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(524);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(82);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(82);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(524);
    sleep(500);
}

void combinePress(int keyOne, int keyTwo) {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(keyOne);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(keyTwo);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(keyTwo);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(keyOne);
}

void combinePress(int keyOne, int keyTwo, int keyThree) {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(keyOne);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(keyTwo);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(keyThree);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(keyThree);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(keyTwo);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(keyOne);
}

void altTab() {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(18);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(9);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(9);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(18);
}

void winD() {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(524);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(68);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(68);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(524);
}

void altF4() {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(18);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(115);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(115);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(18);
}

void enter() {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(10);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(10);
}

void backspace() {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(8);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(8);
}

void sleep(long duration) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(duration);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

void click() {
    MYROBOT.mousePress(16);
    MYROBOT.mouseRelease(16);
}

void doubleClick() {
    click();
    click();
}

void clickNhold(boolean tof) {
    if (tof) {
        MYROBOT.mousePress(16);
    } else {
        MYROBOT.mouseRelease(16);
    }
}

void rightClick() {
    MYROBOT.mousePress(4);
    MYROBOT.mouseRelease(4);
}

void rightclickHold(boolean tof) {
    if (tof) {
        MYROBOT.mousePress(4);
    } else {
        MYROBOT.mouseRelease(4);
    }
}

void middleClick() {
    MYROBOT.mousePress(8);
    MYROBOT.mouseRelease(8);
}

void manuPress(int code) {
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(16);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(code);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(code);
}

void manuPressSHIFTED(int code) {
    MYROBOT.keyPress(16);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(code);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(code);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(16);
}

void gotoxy(int goX, int goY) {
    lastX = X;
    lastY = Y;
    MYROBOT.setAutoDelay(MOUSE_DELAY);
    int initX = X;
    int initY = Y;
    if (goX == X) {
        if (goY > Y) {
            for (int i = Y; i <= goY; i++) {
                Y = i;
                MYROBOT.mouseMove(X, Y);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = Y; i >= goY; i--) {
                Y = i;
                MYROBOT.mouseMove(X, Y);
            }
        }
    } else if (goX > X) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (goX - initX); i++) {
            X = initX + i;
            Y = initY + ((i * (goY - initY)) / (goX - initX));
            MYROBOT.mouseMove(X, Y);
        }

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i >= (goX - initX); i--) {
            X = initX + i;
            Y = initY + ((i * (goY - initY)) / (goX - initX));
            MYROBOT.mouseMove(X, Y);
        }
    }
}

void getRGB(Color pixel) {
    RED = pixel.getRed();
    GREEN = pixel.getGreen();
    BLUE = pixel.getBlue();
    System.out.println(RED + "," + GREEN + "," + BLUE);
}

void savePoint() {
    savedX = X;
    savedY = Y;
}

void captureScreen() {
    System.out.println("Capturing...");
    SCREEN = new Color[SCREEN_X][SCREEN_Y];
    for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_X; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SCREEN_Y / 2; j++) {
            SCREEN[i][j] = MYROBOT.getPixelColor(i, j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Capturing done");
}

void gotoPixel(Color pixel) {
    if (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() != pixel.getRGB()) {
        for (int i = SCREEN_X - 4; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 3; j < SCREEN_Y / 2; j++) {
                if ((MYROBOT.getPixelColor(i, j).getRGB() == pixel.getRGB())) {
                    gotoxy(i, j);
                    i = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() == pixel.getRGB()) {
        while (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() == pixel.getRGB()) {
            gotoxy((X - 1), Y);
        }
    }
}

void emergeFromPixel(Color pixel) {
    if (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() != pixel.getRGB()) {
        for (int i = SCREEN_X - 4; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 3; j < SCREEN_Y / 2; j++) {
                if ((MYROBOT.getPixelColor(i, j).getRGB() == pixel.getRGB())) {
                    MYROBOT.mouseMove(i, j);
                    X = i;
                    Y = j;
                    i = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void shift(char dir) {
    int initX = X;
    Color initPixel;
    dir = Character.toUpperCase(dir);
    switch (dir) {
        case 'L': {
            gotoxy((X - 8), Y);
            initPixel = MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y);
            while (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() == initPixel.getRGB()) {
                gotoxy((X - 1), Y);
            }
            initX = X;
            for (int i = initX; i > initX - 20; i--) {
                if (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(i, Y).getRGB() == initPixel.getRGB()) {
                    gotoxy(i, Y);
                    while (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() == initPixel.getRGB()) {
                        gotoxy((X - 1), Y);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'R': {
            initPixel = MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y);
            while (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() == initPixel.getRGB()) {
                gotoxy((X + 1), Y);
            }
            initX = X;
            for (int i = initX; i < initX + 20; i++) {
                if (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(i, Y).getRGB() == initPixel.getRGB()) {
                    gotoxy(i, Y);
                    while (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() == initPixel.getRGB()) {
                        gotoxy((X + 1), Y);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            gotoxy((X + 8), Y);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void emergeFromButton(String butName) {
    int tempDelay = TYPE_DELAY;
    TYPE_DELAY = 0;
    MYROBOT.setAutoDelay(TYPE_DELAY);
    butName = butName.toUpperCase();
    if (butName.equals("CLOSE")) {
        emergeFromPixel(PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE);
    } else if (butName.equals("MAXIMIZE")) {
        emergeFromPixel(PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE);
        shift('L');
    } else if (butName.equals("MINIMIZE")) {
        emergeFromPixel(PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE);
        shift('L');
        shift('L');
    } else if (butName.equals("START")) {
        MYROBOT.mouseMove(20, SCREEN_Y - 10);
    }
    TYPE_DELAY = tempDelay;
    MYROBOT.setAutoDelay(TYPE_DELAY);
}

void gotoButton(String butName) {
    butName = butName.toUpperCase();
    if (butName.equals("CLOSE")) {
        if (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(X, Y).getRGB() != PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_ON_MOUSE.getRGB()) {
            gotoPixel(PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE);
        }
    } else if (butName.equals("MAXIMIZE")) {
        gotoPixel(PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE);
        shift('L');
    } else if (butName.equals("MINIMIZE")) {
        gotoPixel(PIX_CLOSE_ACTIVE_OFF_MOUSE);
        shift('L');
        shift('L');
    } else if (butName.equals("START")) {
        gotoxy(20, SCREEN_Y - 10);
    }
}

void catchTitleBar() {
    gotoButton("CLOSE");
    gotoxy(X - 150, Y);
}

void pressKey(String keyName) {
    keyName = keyName.toUpperCase();
    if (keyName.equals("ESC")) {
        manuPress(27);
    }
}

void closeAllWindows() {
    while ((MYROBOT.getPixelColor(65, SCREEN_Y - 35).getRed() > 213) && (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(65, SCREEN_Y - 35).getGreen() > 220) && (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(65, SCREEN_Y - 35).getBlue() > 228)) {
        altTab();
        gotoButton("CLOSE");
        sleep(100);
        click();
        sleep(50);
    }
}

void quickCloseAllWindows() {
    while ((MYROBOT.getPixelColor(65, SCREEN_Y - 35).getRed() > 213) && (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(65, SCREEN_Y - 35).getGreen() > 220) && (MYROBOT.getPixelColor(65, SCREEN_Y - 35).getBlue() > 228)) {
        winD();
        sleep(100);
        altTab();
        altF4();
        type("n");
    }
}

void getNotepad() {
    int saveDelay = TYPE_DELAY;
    TYPE_DELAY = 0;
    MYROBOT.setAutoDelay(0);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(524);
    MYROBOT.keyPress(82);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(82);
    MYROBOT.keyRelease(524);
    sleep(200);
    typeln("notepad");
    sleep(500);
    TYPE_DELAY = saveDelay;
    MYROBOT.setAutoDelay(TYPE_DELAY);
}

void closeActiveWindow() {
    gotoButton("CLOSE");
    click();
    type("n");
}

void openMyComputer() {
    gotoxy(50, 50);
    doubleClick();
}

void lockMouse() {
    Thread lockMouse = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                MYROBOT.mouseMove(X, Y);
                sleep(100);
            }
        }
    });
    lockMouse.start();
}
```

}

You owe me...

Answer (score 3):

The robot class will work well for what you want to do . check out this tutorial [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2212401/Introduction-to-the-Java-Robot-Class-in-Java.htm)

Also you can look into other automated testing frameworks. One that comes to mind is [testComplete](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CEUQFjAA&url=http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools&ei=y2IOUN_ODoeC2wXCsIGgBg&usg=AFQjCNEuuz3bt7rOiMPGfi_sitMULUCCQw). Are you trying to use this for UI testing purposes?